# is android-priority-job-queue and job scheduler two different things?

Tags: android, jobs

I just want to put my finger on this issue:
is android-priority-job-queue: https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

and 
android job scheduler :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

two different things? or is the android-priority-jobqueue a huge resemblance?

They have similar characteristics, but bottom line my conclusion is that they are two different things.
For example I can schedule a job to run when there is unmetered network using job scheduler, but in job queue I need to configure it.

Am I missing something??
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are two very different things.

The library "Android Priority Job Queue" is intended to solve the problem where you have lots of things you want to run in the background and want a way to manage them so they don't overload your app. The expectation is that you want these bits of work to run as soon as possible and you want to show the results in an activity in your app (but not necessarily).

JobScheduler is used when you have work that needs to be scheduled and run at some time in the future, maybe ever after your app's process has been killed. It's sensitive to device circumstances like deep sleep and network connectivity so work can be scheduled at the best possible time without draining battery.

Comment: Thank you, after diving into it again, what you wrote makes perfect sense. it's very confusing because when searching in google for one topic you get results regarding both. it would have been nice if the guys developing the "priority job queue" would have called it something else :) thanks very much.

Comment: author of android priority jobqueue here. We developed it appx 3-4 years ago, there was no JobScheduler that time :). Though for v2.0, I'm working on making it work with JobScheduler so that you can take advantage of its capabilities using the same interface.

Comment: @yigit Currently i'm working on an app that uses android priority jobqueue, before starting i did compare it between JobScheduler and was able to get the difference but I appreciate it is serving it purpose and looking for upgraded release of the library.